# Why mongodb loose data when adding replicaset to shards

Tags: database, mongodb, sharding

I am facing the problem with (I guess) data loss.
My cluster was set up pn 4 mongo shards (2 (shard zero nad one) of them had already 1 replicaset per shard).
After adding 2 replicasets to shards 2 and 3 data partialy was lost.
Where did this data go?
Can I find it somewhere?

My setup:
2 vms 256GB ram each, 32 cores each
mongodb 6.0.1 built by helmchart

I have tried to look up over internet but I did not quite find the answer.

Before replicaset was 547MiB and over 1.400.000 docks.

After added replicaset:

```
Shard mongo-shard-1 at mongo-shard-1/mongo-shard1-data-0.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-shard1-data-1.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017
{
  data: '93.36MiB',
  docs: 239362,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '93.36MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 239362
}
---
Shard mongo-shard-2 at mongo-shard-2/mongo-shard2-data-0.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-shard2-data-1.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017
{
  data: '93.69MiB',
  docs: 240220,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '93.69MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 240220
}
---
Shard mongo-shard-0 at mongo-shard-0/mongo-shard0-data-0.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-shard0-data-1.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017
{
  data: '93.49MiB',
  docs: 239701,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '93.49MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 239701
}
---
Shard mongo-shard-3 at mongo-shard-3/mongo-shard3-data-0.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-shard3-data-1.mongo-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017
{
  data: '93.44MiB',
  docs: 239563,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '93.44MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 239563
}
---
Totals
{
  data: '373.99MiB',
  docs: 958846,
  chunks: 4,
  'Shard mongo-shard-1': [
    '24.96 % data',
    '24.96 % docs in cluster',
    '408B avg obj size on shard'
  ],
  'Shard mongo-shard-2': [
    '25.05 % data',
    '25.05 % docs in cluster',
    '409B avg obj size on shard'
  ],
  'Shard mongo-shard-0': [
    '24.99 % data',
    '24.99 % docs in cluster',
    '408B avg obj size on shard'
  ],
  'Shard mongo-shard-3': [
    '24.98 % data',
    '24.98 % docs in cluster',
    '408B avg obj size on shard'
  ]
}
[direct: mongos] metadata>
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you count the documents? I guess `getShardDistribution` shows only an estimated number.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it prior and after. Does it mean that no data is lost even if replicaset is added ? Does it always work like this? What method should i use to count in write and look for changes that are accurate?

Comment: Use `db.collection.countDocuments()`

Comment: It is possible for a shard to contain orphaned documents that logically don't belong there any more.  Queries submitted via mongos automatically filter those out, while queries submitted directly to the mongod do not.